# Feed tile notifications with new RSS content

Tags: notifications, rss, windows-10-mobile, microsoft-band

I created a feed webtile for the MS band using the Online authoring tool.  The feed works and updates, however the notifications do not appear when the RSS is updated with something new.  Is there a way to set this up correctly using only the online Authoring tool?  I'm currently attempting to use the pubDate and check it against the date I initially made the tile.  A notification pops up immediately when I add the tile to the band, but never again.  What am I doing wrong? Currently it's set like this:

{{pubDate}} > Wed, 17 Feb 00:00:00 +0000

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The {{pubDate}} will be a string of the format: "Thu, 18 Feb 2016 21:23:49 +0000" which will be compared as a string against your constant "Wed, 17 Feb 00:00:00 +0000". Since the first character that gets compared is "T" against "W" fails the ">" operator, (that is 'T' is not greater than 'W'), the expression returns false. I expect that is not the intent you are going for. I think you may want to compare date strings that consist only of number characters.

Comment: Changing the format of the date string is not an option since my data source is maintained by others.  I changed the notification condition to:{{guid}} is not equal to ... The guid is a hex value that is unique, but is also not sequential.  I will need to wait for the feed to update to see if this works.  There is another issue I discovered.  The party that maintains the RSS doesn't always add new content to the feed at the top.  It seems that certain stories are kept on top, while others are added below.  When the feed updated in this way, the webtile did not update at all. Is this normal?

Comment: The feed webtile engine expects that the feed items will be ordered from newer to older. That is, it iterates through the latest feed contents until it encounters an item that has been seen in an earlier update, then it stops the iteration.

Comment: OK I tried a new approach. Instead of using the Feed tile, I made a multi-page tile where each page shows one of the first 7 items in the feed. This way each item is checked and updated when fetching new data, rather than just the first item. I also set up 7 notifications, one for each page, using guid =/= the original guid. The feed is updating as it should, but there are some drawbacks. The tile doesn't badge with an unread count, and I can only view 7 items vs 8. Also the notification appears at every data fetch. I know why it does that, I just don't know if there's a fix for it. Any ideas?

Comment: Badging is only available for Feed web tiles. For Simple tiles, badging is not available. Also, for Simple tiles a maximum of 7 pages are available for use. For Simple tiles the notification will be evaluated against all the data obtained in an update, and so if the condition remains true then the notification will fire again.

Comment: Yes all of that I figured out already.  What I'm really looking for is a way to store the previous value of guid, so i'm not checking a static value.  Is there a way to do this using only the Online Authoring tool?  I can't find a way, but I might be missing something.

Comment: I am with @MichaelJuliano, the documentation is not very helpful in this case. You should add some samples for valid parameters.

Comment: Webtiles do not support storing user defined data from one update for use by the webtile in the next update.